# Как обновить ветки в git между собой?

Tags: git

Есть главная ветка - Мастер, на её основе созданная другая ветка (для примера Задание_1) , работа идёт в Задании_1, работа выполнена, надо слить изменения в Мастер, но в Мастере уже были произведены слияния с другими ветками и получается, что в Задании_1 остались переменные, функции и т.п. которых уже нет в Мастере и если попытаться слить ветки сейчас, то в Мастере окажутся всё эти изменения, как можно синхронизировать ветки Задании_1 и Мастер, чтобы в Задании_1 появились всё новые изменения из Мастер, но при этом остались те, которые были выполнены в рамках задания?

Comment: Сливаете ветку Master в Задание_1 (или делаете rebase Задание_1 на Master), тестируете, сливаете Задание_1 в Мастер.

Comment: При нормальной работе с ветками такого не будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так объясните, что сделано не нормально, и как делать нормально.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, не знаю, что именно не так, но знаю, что такого быть не должно.